# Stop Eclipse Automatically Closing/Completing Comments

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, comments, eclipse-mars

When working on C code in Eclipse (Mars, in case that matters), I type `/*` to begin a stream comment. If I hit [Enter] any time within this stream comment, Eclipse automatically inserts a column of single-space indented stars `_*` and a single-space indented close stream comment `_*/`. This is incredibly annoying as this is **never** the behavior I want after opening a stream comment. I then have to undo-undo or highlight and delete.

I've gone into `C/C++ > Editor > Typing` and unchecked every option in the `Automatically close` group-box, but these options only include `"Strings"`, `(Parentheses) and [Square Brackets]`, `<Angle> brackets` and `{Braces}`.

There's no `/*Comments*/` option.

I've even tried modifying every code template that contains such a stream comment, to no avail.

**How can I get Eclipse to stop auto-completing comments?**

---

*I've checked these similar questions and found no answer:
[Annoying eclipse automatically closing quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444845/annoying-eclipse-automatically-closing-quotes), [Stop Eclipse from mangling my comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588059/stop-eclipse-from-mangling-my-comments), [eclipse disable completion of xml comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363379/eclipse-disable-completion-of-xml-comment), [How to stop Eclipse from auto-adding parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873331/how-to-stop-eclipse-from-auto-adding-parentheses)*

Comment: That's apparently not about the C language, but the tool. Don't spam tags.

Comment: @Olaf Eclipse is used to code for many languages, and this question is about the C-specific functionality of the tool. If that's not a good reason, I'm sorry.

Comment: @ZakA.Klajda As per the best of my knowledge, there's no such provision in Eclipse Mars for C/C++.